# requests module redirect URL not working with Twitter

Tags: url, python-requests

I want to be able to get the username of a Twitter user using their Twitter user id without using the Twitter API.

I am trying to do this by getting the redirect URL from the requests module (and getting the username from the URL); however, it has not been working.

This is what I have tried:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://twitter.com/i/user/783214')
url = response.url

# should print https://twitter.com/Twitter but prints https://twitter.com/i/user/783214
print(url)
```

Why is the proper redirected URL not being returned here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Twitter does not use an HTTP redirect.

It probably uses a Javascript form of redirection like changing `window.location.href`, requests is not a browser so it does not execute the javascript in the page you requested hence the absence of redirection.